# Conditional match/merge in R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, conditional-statements, match

I have two data frames of unequal number of rows:

```
df1

Label   Country    Year
NU      Germany    1999
BU      Italy      1945
LU      France     2009
KM      Sweden     1998
NU      Germany    1999
```

and

```
df2

Make     Label     
X1       NU
X2       BU
X3       NU
X4       NU
X5       KM
```

What I would like to do is match on "Label" and end up with the following:

```
Make   Label    Country     Year
X1       NU     Germany     1999
X2       BU     Italy       1945
X3       NU     Germany     1999
X4       NU     Germany     1999
X5       KM     Sweden      1998
```

Comment: Probably a duplicate, but `merge(df1, df2, by="Label")` should do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 a=merge(df2,df1,by="Label")
 a[!duplicated(a),]
   Label Make Country Year
 1    BU   X2   Italy 1945
 2    KM   X5  Sweden 1998
 3    NU   X1 Germany 1999
 5    NU   X3 Germany 1999
 7    NU   X4 Germany 1999
```